# Go - Encode nested structure

Tags: json, go

I'm working on an extension of http://gary.burd.info/go-websocket-chat.

This example sends raw text through websockets.

I want to use JSON data instead.

I did some structures in my Go code, but when I convert it to JSON to write it to the client, the nested structures are not in the result.

Some code :

```
type(
    ChatroomData struct {
        Token string `json:"token"`
        Chatroom *Chatroom `json:"chatroom"`
    }
    Message struct {
        Token string `json:"token,omitempty"`
        Type string `json:"type"`
        Author string `json:"author"`
        Content string `json:"content"`
        Chatroom string `json:"chatroom"`
    }
    Messages []Message
)
```

The chatroom struct :

```
Chatroom struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Users []User `json:"users"`
    Messages Messages `json:"messages"`
    Hub *WsHub `json:"-"`
}
Chatrooms map[string]*Chatroom
User struct {
    username string `json:"username"`
    token string `json:"-"`
}
Users []User
```

Start the chatroom :

```
func (s *Server) startMainChatroom() {
    s.Chatrooms["main"] = &Chatroom{
        Name: "main",
        Users: make([]User, 0),
        Messages: make([]Message, 0),
        Hub: NewHub(),
    }
    go s.Chatrooms["main"].Hub.Run()
}
```

The way to append messages to the chatroom :

```
message := Message{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &message)
message.Token = ""
message.Type = "message"
chatroom.Messages = append(chatroom.Messages, message)
```

Send data to the client :

```
func (u *User) SendChatroomData(w http.ResponseWriter, c *Chatroom, status int) {
    chatroomData := ChatroomData{Token: u.token, Chatroom: c}

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, authorization")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST")
    w.WriteHeader(status)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&chatroomData); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The printed result is :

```
{
     "token":"a638ed3ba0c30ba3d0810fc79e12a50a",
     "chatroom":{
         "name":"main",
         "users":[{},{}],
         "messages":[]
     }
}
```

There are two users and three messages were sent. If I use `fmt.Printf("%v\n", chatroom.Messages)`, I have the three messages correctly stored. Same for the users, data is here when I dump it.

Many things are strange :

- Why the `messages` key stays empty ?
- *Why the `users` key doesn't, but the slice items are empty ?* (**solved by Mike Reedell**)

Thank you for your help, don't hesitate to ask me more code if it needs to be. I hope my post isn't already too long (and not too full of english errors X)) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was totally elsewhere : The Chatroom instance I used when adding some messages wasn't bound correctly to `s.Chatrooms["main"]`, due to my misunderstanding of pointers.

When I marshaled `s.Chatrooms["main"]`, the messages weren't inside !

Ty for your help !

I hope this will help some others go-learners :D

Answer (score 1):

The go JSON marshaler will only output exported (capitalized) fields.  The field in the `User` struct are un-exported (lower-case), which means the JSON marshaler doesn't know they are there and can't output them.

Comment: I'm an idiot.. I knew this, I just didn't look. I focused on my main problem with the ``messages`` key. Thank you :D

Comment: @Kern since you have modified the question after the answer, it has become irrelevant. Do you still have a problem, or did that answer actually solve it ? In the latter case, you might want to undo your latest edit because the question does not exhibit any problem that can be reproduced.

Comment: @SirDarius I just did a rollback, hoping that it makes the question more clear ! In fact, I had a main problem with the ``messages`` key of my JSON, I just talked about the ``users`` key thinking it would help to understand the problem.

The messages contained in my ``Chatroom`` struct are just ignored when I marshal them, I don't understand why and this is my main problem !

Ty for your comment :) !